# when i carry out official document ‘test-network’,Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

my fabric version is v2.2.1 and my docker images are

```
ev-peer0.org2.example.com-basic_1.0-4ec191e793b27e953ff2ede5a8bcc63152cecb1e4c3f301a26e22692c61967ad-6c0d5b0755cb92ed5555bd2e8a8765a6f425d1ed5ed9a90e625e01939e2113be   latest              a123e0b8baaf        21 minutes ago      22.4MB
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic_1.0-4ec191e793b27e953ff2ede5a8bcc63152cecb1e4c3f301a26e22692c61967ad-42f57faac8360472e47cbbbf3940e81bba83439702d085878d148089a1b213ca   latest              b7b0157c45ec        21 minutes ago      22.4MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                                                                    1.4                 dbbc768aec79        3 weeks ago         158MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                                                                    1.4.9               dbbc768aec79        3 weeks ago         158MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                                                                    latest              dbbc768aec79        3 weeks ago         158MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                                                                                 2.2                 e9b802fadb41        3 weeks ago         519MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                                                                                 2.2.1               e9b802fadb41        3 weeks ago         519MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                                                                                 latest              e9b802fadb41        3 weeks ago         519MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                                                                                  2.2                 ece149884124        3 weeks ago         55MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                                                                                  2.2.1               ece149884124        3 weeks ago         55MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                                                                                  latest              ece149884124        3 weeks ago         55MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                                                                               2.2                 78a16ddd2cf4        3 weeks ago         38.4MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                                                                               2.2.1               78a16ddd2cf4        3 weeks ago         38.4MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                                                                               latest              78a16ddd2cf4        3 weeks ago         38.4MB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                                                                                 2.2                 8e554c280cac        3 weeks ago         586MB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                                                                                 2.2.1               8e554c280cac        3 weeks ago         586MB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                                                                                 latest              8e554c280cac        3 weeks ago         586MB
hyperledger/fabric-baseos                                                                                                                                                2.2                 0b99d26b26ad        3 weeks ago         6.85MB
hyperledger/fabric-baseos                                                                                                                                                2.2.1               0b99d26b26ad        3 weeks ago         6.85MB
hyperledger/fabric-baseos                                                                                                                                                latest              0b99d26b26ad        3 weeks ago         6.85MB
couchdb                                                                                                                                                                  3.1                 6cc07e2c5651        5 weeks ago         190MB
busybox                                                                                                                                                                  latest              6858809bf669        6 weeks ago         1.23MB
hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv                                                                                                                                               2.2                 ab88fe4d29dd        3 months ago        293MB
```

I follow the official documentation steps

```
./network up createChannel
./network deployCC
```

and configure the corresponding path
however, when I perform a peer operation

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

the following error occurred

```
Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/peng/go/src/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

what can I do for it?
help me please
thanks very much

Comment: As you can read at you logs, it says that your `KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo` so, it seems that you haven't generated the requiered crypto material. Could you verify if you have created it?

Comment: in msp dictionary i only have there

admincerts   keystore   keystore   keystore   keystore

Comment: I have edited my response

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the crypto material have not been created well, because you haven't executed correctly the `network.sh script`. As it is mentioned at the official documentation test tutorial, you have to execute the following steps:

1. Create network and start up components executing the following comnand: `./network.sh up`
2. Create the channel executing the following command: `./network.sh createChannel`
3. And finally, deploy the Smart Contract with the following command: `./network.sh deployCC`

However, you indicate that you execute the following command: `./network up createChannel` The script only accepts a parameter, so, it would be executed wrongly. Before trying it again, you should remove you docker containers and docker volumes.

*--Edited to add more info*

It should be because you have generated many times the crypto material and, you have many private keys. The public keys have been replaced but, new private keys were added. So, probably the Blockchain is using the incorrect private key. Could you remove the organizations generated with the cryptogen and generate again the crypto material?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, ,The same error still occurs after I separate the instructions, and the script still fails after I execute ```sudo .\network.sh down``` command and delete the corresponding key file.I suspect there is an error in the file of the official website ```test-Network.``` I am checking the problem, whether it is a path problem or not. I had corresponding problems before

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. As you can see `./network up createChannel` and `./network deployCC`
These scripts ran successfully, although they still used your peer certificates. What I found was, that there must be a mismatch in the certificates that were generated by `cryptogen` tool vs 'fabric-ca'.

Since you are using Fabric v2.2.x, first bring the network down by running:
'sudo ./network.sh down' in your directory

After that run: `sudo ./network.sh up -ca`. Here
`-ca` will setup the network with 'fabric-ca' client.

Now deploy the chaincode: `sudo ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript -ccl javascript`

After deploying the chain-code you have invoke it. For invocation, we need access the msp certificates. The `fabric-ca` will not allow you to access `/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`. So you have to use your CLI as super mode:
Run: `sudo -s`

Now let us set the environmental variables:
`export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH`
`export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/`
Environment variables for Org1

`export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true`
`export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"`
`export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt`
`export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`
`export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051`

Now run this command: `peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'`

If successful, you should see similar output:
`-> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200`